# Rename [coremidi] to [core-midi] to match the "core-" pattern

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Core Midi is a Framework for iOS and OS X, its current tag is [coremidi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coremidi). All other Apple Core-Frameworks are named with a dash. e.g. [core-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-data), [core-bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-bluetooth), [core-graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-graphics), [core-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-location).

That's why [coremidi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coremidi) should be renamed to [core-midi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-midi).